# SpringBoot Aruba Mail

Tags: spring-boot, email, smtp

I want to send a mail with Aruba host and `SpringBoot 2.1.3` application. Before start I have done a little test, believing I would have found no problem.. I was wrong.

This is my `application.properties`

```
spring.mail.host=smtps.aruba.it
spring.mail.port=465
spring.mail.username=***
spring.mail.password=***
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.debug=true
```

Don't works, the debug says me that it cant connect to the hosts.. and, while it trying to do it, the debugger write:

```
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtps.aruba.it", port 465, isSSL false
```

What's wrong?? I trying to send mail with *gmail* and *hotmail* with the same parameters and all works well.. damned Aruba..

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
spring.mail.host=smtps.aruba.it
spring.mail.port=465
spring.mail.username=***
spring.mail.password=***
spring.mail.protocol=smtp
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.port=465
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.class=javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback=false
```

Hope helps..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure about it but try to use as host smtp without "s" cause you are not using a secure SSL connection:

```
smtp.aruba.it
```

More informations : https://serversmtp.com/smtp-aruba/

Comment: No I must use it! I tried to add the account to Thunderbird and this is the default choice and all works well. Instead I think the problem is the security because with Hotmail and Gmail is STARTTLS and with Aruba is SSL/TLS and I didn't find yet a way to set it with SpringBoot. Thanks anyway

Comment: I'll try to create an account and try to solve it with u, if I have any news I'll let you know here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use STARTTLS switch to port 587, port 465 is for implicit SSL not for explicit

```
spring.mail.host=smtps.aruba.it
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=***
spring.mail.password=***
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

Answer (score 0):

At the present moment the configuration you have written is not right.
The protocol is smtps.
The right configuration in application.properties for sending an email with aruba and spring boot is the following one:

```
spring.mail.host=smtps.aruba.it
spring.mail.port=465
spring.mail.username=*** your email address ***
spring.mail.password=*** the password of your email ***
spring.mail.protocol=smtps
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.port=465
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.class=javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback=false
```